# Is my pinia store correctly initialized with vue3?

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, pinia

I have this vue 3 app which i want to manage some status of my dnd players.
This is my main.js file

```
import { createApp } from "vue";
import { createPinia } from "pinia";
import App from "./App.vue";

const pinia = createPinia();

createApp(App).use(pinia).mount("#app");
```

I can change all states in the store using actions without problem, however, I also use a getter to change a state called "Status", but most of the time (sometimes it works) it is like it is not initializing and I cannot change it.

Also, I use Vue Devtools to check it and whenever it happens, Pinia is not found on it.
So, is my storage being initilized correctly?

This is my getter:
getters: {

```
    statusChange: (state) => {
        state.characters.forEach((character) => {
            if (character.failures === 0 && character.successess === 0) {
                return (character.status = "");
            }
            if (character.failures === 3 && character.successess === 3) {
                return (character.status = "Schrodinger's cat");
            }
            if (character.failures === 3) {
                return (character.status = "Dead");
            }
            if (character.successess === 3) {
                return (character.status = "Alive");
            }
            return (character.status = "Risky");
        });
    },
},
```

And this is how I initialize the Store:

```
import { useStatusStore } from "../../stores/StatusStore";
const statusStore = useStatusStore();
```

Comment: It looks like you're using getters for the wrong purpose.  A getter shouldn't be in charge of mutating state, that's the job of actions (they're called _getters_ for a reason and not _setters_).  Getters are just computed properties behind the scenes and are meant for only returning state or calculating some result based on state (without mutating it).  It'll depend on your exact requirements but likely you should refactor this getter to become an action that is maybe called as a follow-up action whenever character.failures or character.successes is changed?

Comment: Yeah! You were right, now it is working as it should! 
Thanks a lot xD